# Select the highest value from mixed string/int column in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a column as `varchar`. I stored the value in it as follows:-

```
P.ID
P1
P2
.
.
P6
.
P11
```

I want to select only the highest `id` from this column e.g: `p11` is my highest id.

My existing query is :

```
SELECT top(1) P.ID as Result from P order by P.ID desc
```

Comment: Sample data and expected result will be helpful

Comment: @Sreenu131 sample data is provided. expected output is p11 because it is highest id from that column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple method is:

```
select top (1) pid
from p
order by len(pid) desc, pid desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to what you provide, you can do

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(RIGHT(YourColumn, LEN(YourColumn)-1) AS BIGINT))
FROM TBL;
```

eg:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 'P1' AS Col
  UNION
  SELECT 'P2'
  UNION
  SELECT 'P100'
)
SELECT MAX(CAST(RIGHT(Col, LEN(Col)-1) AS BIGINT))
FROM CTE;
```

Which will returns: `100`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select top 1 *
from P
order by cast(substring(P.ID, 2, len(P.ID)) as int) desc
```

It just orders by integer number contained in your column.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
;WITH CTE ([P.ID])
AS
(
SELECT 'P1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'P2' UNION ALL
SELECT 'P6' UNION ALL
SELECT 'P11' 
)
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM CTE
ORDER BY  CAST(SUBSTRING([P.ID],PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',[P.ID]),LEN([P.ID])) AS INT) DESC
```

Result

```
P.ID
----
P11
```